Bug in TSSRESTREND package in R
I am busy learning how to apply a Residual Trend analysis in R using the TSSRESTREND package and encountered a problem. I tried several of the examples provided in the package to get acquainted with the scripts but it always fails at a specific point and gives the error message below in R studio:
results <- TSSRESTREND(CTSR.VI, ACP.table)
Error in (class(ACP.table) == "logical") && (!CTSR.RF || acu.RF) : 
  'length = 2' in coercion to 'logical(1)  

The ACP.table and CTSR.VI was created in my opinion correctly in previous steps. I have installed and re-installed the latest version 3.2 and tried several examples provided in the package.

Welcome to SO! I'm afraid there's no way to reproduce this exact issue without having access to your CTSR.VI &  ACP.table objects. Please edit your question to include those objects in a reproducible form, output from dput(CTSR.VI) & dput(ACP.table) would be ideal but you may need to subset a smaller section from those. Or use same datasets used in examples in documentation, ?TSSRESTREND.  Or include some code to generate example toy data. Just make sure it fails in a same way as with your real datasets.

Also keep in mind that for reproducibility, others should be able to just copy and paste your example code and run it, i.e. please do not refer to files that are only available in your system, do not omit library() calls etc. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language/articles/76995406/how-to-write-a-good-r-question-with-a-reproducible-example & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example for more more details.
